# undefined is not and object(eveluting 'days[0].clone') in react-native-calendars library

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars, react-native-render-html

async componentWillMount() {

```
this.setState({
  mMonthStartDate: moment(new Date()).startof('month').format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  userAcadDetails: this.props.user.userAcadInfo,
  item: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getAsyncValue("""""""""""))
})
```

**render Method**

```
      <Calendar
        style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width }}
        current={this.state.mMonthStartDate}
        minDate={this.state.mMonthStartDate}
        maxDate={this.state.mMonthEndDate}
        onMonthChange={month => {
          // this.getStartdate(month.dateString);
          console.log("month changed", month);
        }}
      />
```

**I am not able to crack this whenever debug JS remotely is on Application perfect. when i turn it off this error will display**

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was using markedDates={{}} prop and the reason was that I wasn't passing valid date format which was (YYYY-MM-DD) rather than I was passing (YYYY-M-D).
eg :-
Valid - 2021-06-06
Invalid - 2021-6-6

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. [You can search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Actually, this did provide an answer to the question. This is a question specific to the parsing of this library's dates under the hood. The problem is not the user's code. It's the library's code. I did the same thing, but with `current` rather than `markedDates`, and this answer helped me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> Note:
>   These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new
>   code:
>   UNSAFE_componentWillMount()

I would recommend doing your fetching and async stuff inside of `componentDidMount()`. The problem is probably that you are trying to set or use some values that are not available atm.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened for me when I passed wrong date format in the `selected` property of `<Agenda />` component. I fixed the issue by providing the date in correct format i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`.